# Как правильно скопировать объект

Tags: gwt, javascript, java

Как правильно скопировать объект события в GWT? Нашел такой код:

```
private static native Object сopy(Object obj)/*-{
     if (typeof obj !== 'object' || obj === null) {
         return obj;
     }
    var c = new Object();
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            if (typeof obj[i] !== 'object' || obj[i] === null)
                c[i] = obj[i];
        }
    }
    return c;
}-*/;
```

Вызываю так:

```
 MouseDownEvent e = (MouseDownEvent)copy((Object)event);
```

Но он сыплет исключениями. Что в этом коде ошибочного? Есть ли возможность не использовать нативный код для **глубокого** копирования объекта?

Comment: Нет смысла пытаться приводить насильно event к Object: любой объект и так сам легко приводится к Object.

Comment: Какие хоть ошибки-то? Этот код по идее правильный. Ошибки при копировании или при использовании копии?

Comment: При копировании.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить, что obj имеет какой-то свой тип, отличный от типа Object. Поэтому результат лучше создавать как obj.constructor(). И из-за выбора оператора сравнения. В интернете есть такой пример:

```
>> window.hello
null
>> window.hello == null
true
>> window.hello === null
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что этот код не работает, потому, что c не объявлена. Надо перед циклом for сделать

```
var c = new Object();
```

Comment: Нет, не оно.